# XLS Strange behavior in formatting date in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, date

I have a basic problem in Excel and in `libreoffice`.

all the dates numbers are entered in the sheet as `80710` (see the first picture, in the preview panel) then excel displays them as `8-07-10` but I want them sorted and display a fuller date as `2010 Jully 8`

Here illustrated in excel: [image]

I am trying to display the dates better (Such as `12 march 2013`)  and, if possible, to sort the date field.

I have a B column which are supposed to be dates, presented in the sheet as

```
dd-mm-yy
```

(I translate everything in english)

But once I type `dd-mm-yy` in the preview, the number

```
80710
```

It becomes:

[image]

but the number `80710` should be `8 Jully 2010`

Comment: this did work to display the hidden columns. thank you.

Comment: yes but the number `80710` should be `8 Jully 2010`

Comment: this works, but I want to convert all the numbers `80710 ` into directly the full date, instead of re-entering everything as `8/7/2010` to get the full date.

Comment: but you dont have 80710 number at all

Comment: I do, all the numbers are entered in the sheet as `80710 ` (see the first picture, in the preview panel) then excel displays them as `8-07-10`  but I want them sorted and display a fuller date like `8 Jully 2010` or  better, as `2010 Jully 8`

Comment: I think you wrong. 1. Or You dont have 80710 values in cell 2. Or you using formulas or VBA to format them as date.  So please attach a xls file so we can see that you doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VALUE("20"&RIGHT(A1,2)&"/"&IF(LEN(A1)=5,MID(A1,2,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1),MID(A1,3,2)&"/"&LEFT(A1,2)))
```

Comment: where should I enter this formula ?

Comment: I do not follow. I copy the totality of the original column with the `80710`, then paste it into a new column with special paste and I choose values. But when and where do I enter your formula ?

Comment: I have excel 2002 on this machine. I have copied the original column with the 80710 in a new sheet, in the A column. I paste the formula in a B column  but I have  an ''error in the formula'' without explanation. Excel highlight the first `A1,2` in `RIGHT(A1,2)` and the cell A1 is in blue.

Comment: the formula works with `;`, but in excel I get #NOM? in the column B but the formula works in `libreoffice`, for most dates. The pictures are here : http://imgur.com/a/NzMBu and the dates of the  column A is http://pastebin.com/GqteDXEk

Comment: I managed to get it work and to sort the dates ! thank you to everybody

Answer (score 0):

Select columns A:G and press right mouse button and press unhide

Also pay attention that date format is locale sensitivity and in your case should be "aa-mm-jj" not "dd-mm-yy"

```
80710 must be 2120-12-21
40367 must be 2010-07-08
```

You wrong understanding of converting dates
in your case you need write date separator, without date separator Excel understand date as serial number

Answer (score 0):

In it's most basic explanation - dates are stored in Excel as a number, from 00/01/1900 + *n* days (assuming your are on a Windows OS).

For example:
0 = 00/01/1900
1 = 01/01/1900
2 = 02/01/1900
...

So when you enter 80710, Excel reads this as "00/01/1900 + 80,710 days" which would be 21/12/2120

Based on this example, 08/07/2010 is 40,367 days after 00/01/1900 and so the value you are looking for is: `40367`

Your sheet isn't showing a date, it's showing a string in a custom format.

Comment: I understand better indeed. Is it possible to convert all my numbers into the correct one to display the correct dates ?

Comment: I would use a helper column, and then try the formula that @pnuts has kindly provided.